# pass enter key from Java to Shell script

Tags: java, unix, jsch

I am trying a Java program to run multiple commands in unix environment. I would need to pass 'ENTER' after each command. Is there some way to pass enter in the InputStream.

```
        JSch jsch=new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession("MYUSERNAME", "SERVER", 22);
        session.setPassword("MYPASSWORD");
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        Channel channel= session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setInputStream(getInputStream("ls -l"));
        channel.setInputStream(getInputStream("\r\n"));
        channel.setInputStream(getInputStream("pwd"));
        channel.setInputStream(getInputStream("\r\n"));
        channel.connect();
```

When I do ls -l, I want to add enter here, so that the command is executed.
getInputStream is a method to convert String into InputStream.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You send enter ( '\n' ) to the input stream.

Comment: It just creates a new line into the command line. It does not do the enter.

Comment: You mean you want to send enter to the input of the shell? It isn't clear what you are asking. Try posting a (minimal) piece of code and explaining what is not working.

Comment: I have modified the question to add the program. it is currently \r\n, which is not working. It just is creating a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JSch javadoc, you must call `setInputStream()` or `getOutputStream()` before `connect()`.  You can only do one of these, once.

For your purposes, `getOutputStream()` seems more appropriate. Once you have an OutputStream, you can wrap it in a PrintWriter to make sending commands easier.

Similarly you can use `channel.getInputStream()` to acquire an InputStream from which you can read results.

```
OutputStream os = channel.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os);
InputStream is = channel.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
channel.connect();
writer.println("ls -l");
String response = reader.readLine();
while(response != null) {
    // do something with response
    response = reader.readLine();
}
writer.println("pwd");
```

If you're determined to use `setInputStream()` instead of `getOutputStream()` then you can only do that once, so you'll have to put all your lines into one String:

```
    channel.setInputStream(getInputStream("ls -l\npwd\n"));
```

(I don't think you need `\r`, but add it back in if necessary)

If you're not familiar with working with streams, writers and readers, do some study on these before working with JSch.